# Indicator doesn't stop in Xcode 9. Is there a way out?

Tags: swift, xcode9

I am finding the activity indicator in the Xcode 9 is not able to "jump to definitions". Is there a way out? Please refer to the image.

[image: Jump to definition is stuck]

Comment: Please see this video, it is not getting dismissed ..  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0Z9YtAkQmIaalR1bzEzVmlsVkE

Comment: how it behave if you goto some other tab and come back?

Comment: I closed the tab, still the same behaviour persists.

Answer (score 0):

You should **scroll a little on the page** and the indicator will dismiss itself.

This is a bug in Xcode 9 and is, indeed, very annoying.